# Mirroring Quaternions

Tags: quaternions

For testing my quaternion averaging algorithm I would like to setup a function that generates an amount of random quaternions where the mean is known. Feeding these quaternions to my function should lead then to the same result as expected by the testing function.

My idea was to represent the quaternion in the angle axis representation (source [www.eater.net/quaternions/video/intro](http://www.eater.net/quaternions/video/intro)).

$q=\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta)(ai+bj+ck)$

With this representation I thought to generate a random normalized quaternion by getting three random numbers for $\theta$, $a$, $b$ and $c$. then just rotate it about an angle of $(\theta+\pi/2)$.
Does this make sense? My quaternions do not turn out the right way. Could you give me a hint where my misunderstanding is?

Here I also got the function in C++ where I want to mirror my quaternions around the quaternion(1,0,0,0) defined in WXYZ:

```
void getTwoMirroredQuaternions(Eigen::Vector4d& quaternion1,
                                         Eigen::Vector4d& quaternion2) {
  double PI = 3.14159265359;

  double i = getRandomNumber();
  double j = getRandomNumber();
  double k = getRandomNumber();

  i = i/(pow(i,2) + pow(j,2) + pow(k,2));
  j = j/(pow(i,2) + pow(j,2) + pow(k,2));
  k = k/(pow(i,2) + pow(j,2) + pow(k,2));

  std::cout << "i: " << i << " j: " << j << " k: " << k << std::endl;

  double realAngle = getRandomNumber();

  double realPart1 = std::cos(realAngle);
  double iPart1 = std::sin(realAngle)*i;
  double jPart1 = std::sin(realAngle)*j;
  double kPart1 = std::sin(realAngle)*k;

  double realPart2 = std::cos(realAngle+PI/2);
  double iPart2 = std::sin(realAngle+PI/2)*i;
  double jPart2 = std::sin(realAngle+PI/2)*j;
  double kPart2 = std::sin(realAngle+PI/2)*k;

  quaternion1.x() = iPart1;
  quaternion1.y() = jPart1;
  quaternion1.z() = kPart1;
  quaternion1.w() = realPart1;

  quaternion2.x() = iPart2;
  quaternion2.y() = jPart2;
  quaternion2.z() = kPart2;
  quaternion2.w() = realPart2;

  quaternion1.normalize();
  quaternion2.normalize();
}
```

Comment: _Does this make sense?_ - No.  What does "mirror" mean?  Are you just considering straight (linear) averages?

Comment: I am familiar with quaternions but not with programming. You need way more context to explain what you want and what you think your program is doing.

Comment: The averaging algorithm I implemented according to the following paper: https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/10.2514/1.28949

To test my implementation I would like to generate a set of quaternions where I know the resulting mean quaternion. My idea is to generate this quaternions in pairs where each of this pairs direct average is the resulting average. Feeding many of these pairs into my algorithm should lead to the known resulting quaternion. 

So the goal is to have a set of quaternions where I know the average of.